# Can I use images and resources available with GPL3 code?

Tags: mit, gpl-3, gpl-2

I would like to use images available in a GitHub repository that is marked with GPL3 license. If I proper reference it, can I use and modify it without author's explicit consent?

If so, is it still valid for MIT and GPL2 licenses?

Comment: Why do you think you couldn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, but unless stated elsewhere in the repository, it seems reasonable to assume the image is GPLv3 if the repository, as a whole, is marked as GPLv3. If I were you, I might attempt to do some investigation (e.g. look through commit history) to the origin of the image to double check that it is indeed GPLv3.

> If I proper reference it, can I use and modify it without author's explicit consent?

Correct, you do not need to get the author's consent to use a GPLv3 image. However, you should include any relevant copyright information from the source of the image (look for copyright in the git repository).

> If so, is it still valid for MIT and GPL2 licenses?

No, it is not valid to include a GPLv3 image in a MIT or GPLv2 licensed project. GPLv3 is not compatible with either of those licenses. However, you could do the reverse. You could use a "GPLv2 or any later version" licensed or MIT licensed image in a GPLv3 project.

Open source license compatibility chart: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_compatibility#/media/File:Floss-license-slide-image.png

Make sure to comply with **all** of the requirements (not just the copyright requirement) of the GPLv3 if you choose to use that license.

https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html

https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-general-public-license-v3-(gpl-3)

Comment: Good catch @apsillers. The "New Compatible Licenses" section of this GNU site, https://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.en.html, confirms your understanding of GPLv2 only being compatible with version 3 if it says "or any later version". Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I will update my answer.